# Generating function of alternating even terms in the Vandermonde Convolution

Tags: generating-functions

I have

\begin{equation}
G(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}  \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^i \binom{k}{2i} \binom{n-k}{r} x^{2i} x^{r} = \frac{1}{2} \left( (1 + x{\iota})^{k} + (1 - x \iota)^{k} \right)(1 + x)^{n-k}
\end{equation}

where $\iota$ is the imaginary unit, i.e., $\iota^2 = -1$. The $l$th term of the above is the alternating sum of even coefficients in the Vandermonde convolution, with $l \le k$. I am interested in obtaining a form of the $l$th term that involves a single binomial coefficient (as in the Vandermonde convolution) as opposed to the convolution of two binomial coefficients. Is there a way to do so?

Edit: Sorry, I needed to explain better. By the $l$th term I mean the coefficient of $x^l$. If we fix such an $l$, then we see that for $i = 0, 1, \ldots $, we have $r = l - 0, l - 2, \ldots $, and therefore fixing $r = l - 2i$, we obtain the following as the coefficient of $x^l$:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{i} \binom{k}{2i} \binom{n-k}{l - 2i}$

So, for instance, if $l = 3$, we get

$\binom{k}{0} \binom{n-k}{3 - 0} - \binom{k}{2} \binom{n-k}{3 - 2}$, where I have used the convention that $\binom{a}{b} = 0$ if $a < b$.

The Vandermonde convolution is:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \binom{k}{i} \binom{n-k}{l - i} = \binom{n}{l}$.

I was hoping to get something like the RHS of the above, i.e., $\binom{n}{l}$, for the $l$th term of the main equation. Note that the inner sum in the main equation has the closed form $(1 + x)^{n-k}$, and the outer sum has the closed form $\frac{1}{2}\left((1 + x\iota)^k + (1 - x\iota)^k\right)$. Please bear in mind the difference between $i$ and $\iota$.

Comment: The inner sum is just a binomial expansion.

Comment: You also need to clarify what $l$ means.

Answer (score 1):

$$(-1)^i x^{2 i} \binom{k}{2 i} (x+1)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Can you explain?  The answer is supposed to depend on some value $l$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay The sum was obtained by Mathematica (I am too lazy), as for $l,$ I am pretty sure the OP means $i$ (as you see, there is no $l$ in the question).

Comment: True, but there is an $x$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Sorry, fixed.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^l$ can be expressed in terms of Krawtchouk polynomials. See Proposition 1.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1798.pdf. I doubt whether there is a "reasonable" formula involving only a single binomial coefficient.